# Ulem package : horizontal line is too thin

Tags: ulem

The slanted lines are correct regarding the size of characters, but horizontal isn't. How to correct that ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
    BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
    SmallCapsFont=*-SmallCaps,
    SmallCapsFont=*-Regular,
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
    ]
\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
    Scale=MatchLowercase,% or MatchUppercase
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-regular,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
    ]   

\usefonttheme{serif}            % Nécessaire pour Fourier
\usepackage{ulem}               % barrer des caractères


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

{\Huge \xout{123} -- \sout{123}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do `\renewcommand` for `\ULthickness` (the default value is 0.4pt). If, additionally, you want that the strike out line is level with the hyphen, you have to modify the definition of `\sout` too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
    BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
    SmallCapsFont=*-SmallCaps,
    SmallCapsFont=*-Regular,
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
    ]
\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
    Scale=MatchLowercase,% or MatchUppercase
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-regular,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
    ]   

\usepackage{ulem}               % barrer des caractères
\renewcommand{\sout}{\bgroup \ULdepth=-.45ex \ULset} % was -0.55ex
\renewcommand{\ULthickness}{1.35pt}                  % was 0.4pt

\begin{document}
\Huge \xout{123} -- \sout{123}
\end{document}
```

I used `article` for making the example “more minimal”. The values have been found by trial and error.

[image]